# Flutter error on using local_auth package and conflicts with other packages

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, mobile, package

I am trying to use `local_auth` package in a Flutter app, but each time I use it, it throws an error:

```bash
I/flutter (25592): Error: no_fragment_activity
```

I know I have to set my `MainActivity.kt` file to extend from `FlutterFragmentActivity` instead of `FlutterActivity`, but the issue is that other dependencies like `flutter_barcode_scanner` `firebase_core` requires the other way around, so I have a conflict.

Is it possible to still use `local_auth` with `FlutterActivity` or should I just find an alternative?

I tried to set the `MainActivity.kt` to `FlutterFragmentActivity`, but many other packages just throw `MethodChannelException` when using it.

Comment: I have also put the FlutterFragmentActivity in MainActivity.kt with the firebase_core and scanner packages and there is no issue. So share your MainActivity.kt code along with the error after the alteration to FlutterFragmentActivity.